# How to see if user has redeemed voucher and then made an actual purchase in r

Tags: r, dataframe, date, filter, dplyr

I have two data frames in r. The first dataframe shows information of users who redeemed a voucher. Here is an idea of what it looks like with mock data.

```
      redeemed redeemed_at user_id             code 
   1:     TRUE  2019-06-04     1           voucher1     
   2:     TRUE  2019-06-04     279         voucher1     
   3:     TRUE  2019-06-04    1501         voucher1     
   4:     TRUE  2019-06-04     967         voucher1     
   5:     TRUE  2019-06-04    1006         voucher1     
  ---                                                                        
1052:     TRUE  2020-08-14    9340         voucher5   
1053:     TRUE  2020-08-18   10123         voucher5    
1054:     TRUE  2020-08-23   10347         voucher5    
1055:     TRUE  2020-08-05     759         voucher5     
1056:     TRUE  2020-08-13   14339         voucher5
```

the other data frame shows account information of users who added credits to their accounts. This means the data set shows all users who made a purchase in the app.

```
    partner_id old_balance_credit credit_added create_date
   1:         11               60.0            10  2019-06-22
   2:        236                10.0           20  2019-06-01
   3:        218               122.0           10  2019-06-02
   4:        814                30.0           20  2019-06-03
   5:        743                20.0           10  2019-06-05
  ---                                                       
5083:      12378                20.0           30  2020-09-18
5084:       2427                43.4           50  2020-09-21
5085:      12011                35.0           80  2020-09-20
5086:      12235                68.2           40  2020-09-20
5087:         21                23.7           40  2020-09-20
```

Note: partner_id = user_id. There are some users who added credits and are listed in the second data frame that have never redeemed a voucher and are not in the first data frame. There are also users who redeemed a voucher but never added credits.

The problem that I am having is that I want to see if the vouchers where a success. I do this by seeing from the users that redeemed a voucher if they are in the second data frame and if the date where credits added is later or equal to the date when the voucher was redeemed.

How do I identify the users whose IDs are in both data frames and where the time they have redeemed it at is less than or equal to the time when they added credits.

Comment: You need some sort of join. Try something like `dplyr::inner_join(df2, df1, by = c("partner_id" = "user_id"))` and then filter by date (alternatively use a non-equijoin in data.table to do this in one step)

Comment: It would be easier to help if you add 10-15 rows (real or fake) of both the dataframes and show us the expected output based on that.